# Using set input for stdin based on output from stdout with python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I would like to install a software automatically from python using subprocess.Popen. During the installation, this software outputs some information and then asks user a couple of questions (e.g., whether to agree with the software license or to install the software). For these questions, I would like to answer them automatically from the pythong code. However, I tried several ways but none of them worked for me. Any idea of how to make it? The expected pseudo code is as follows (definitely, this code does not work).

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['myprogram'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT))

while (p.poll() == None):
  line = p.stdout.readline()
  if not line: 
    break
  else:
    print line.strip()
    if line == 'Do you accept license agreement (YES/NO)':
      p.stdin.write('YES/n')
    elif line == 'Do you want to install this software (YES/NO)':
      p.stdin.write('YES/n')
```

Comment: have you tried https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect?

Comment: Don't write `'YES/n'` if you mean `'YES\n'`. Besides, the `line` might contain a `\n` at the end; `print line.strip()` won't do then. Instead, do `line = line.strip()` at the appropriate time.

Comment: Besides, it could be better style to do `for line in p.stdout:` or `for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):`.

Comment: You are right, it should be 'YES\n'. However, that point is not important. The problem is that when there is a question that requires input from user, the program suspends (that question is not even displayed/retrieved). When I forced stop it, I found that it was waiting at p.stdout.readline(). Thus, don't know what to do.

Comment: I tried the pexpect as suggested by Thomas Fenz. But it didn't work. In particular, I made the following code p = pexpect.spawn('my program') p.expect('Do you accept license agreement (YES/NO)') p.sendline('YES'). But I got a timeout error. I guess that because the output from license agreement is long and hence the parsing generates timeout

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Thomas Fenz. pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect is excellent in this case. In my previous comment, I said it didn't work because I made a mistake in the pattern specification. In particular, I used p.expect('Do you accept license agreement? (YES/NO)'). The question mark in this case was a mistake. As it is a meta character, the pattern could not be matched and hence TIMEOUT happened.